# SQLite typlessness and PRIMARY KEY change

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sqlite2

For some reason in searching for data types the SQLite 2 documentation [SQLite 2 documentation on typlessness](https://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html) came up and I read up on typlessness. I later came to realize that version 2's last release was in 2004. I then searched for version's 3 documentation [SQLite 3 documentation](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and realized that the word 'typeless' does not show up however it appears that the feature was maintained in version 3. Is there a switch in terminology now from 'typelessness' to 'dynamic typing'?

Also, I tried changing the primary key [version 2's documentation says I can't] in a test database and I was able to change it.

[image: Table schema]
[image: Changing primary key]

Is SQLite 3 then not typeless and can the primary key be changed in SQLite3?

---

EDIT: Thanks to Varro, I tried the following and was able to see that I can't put in a string as an id. I also tried inserting an extra row and the id automatically added was 11 and not 2 even though the numbering began at 1 but was changed to 10. So it seems that SQLite checks the previous integer before choosing what to the next row should be numbered.

[image: Trying string for id PRIMARY KEY]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (barring explicit constraints), you can insert a value of any type into any column in SQLite, but a notable exception is if you declare a column `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, which means that it's an alias for the internal (integer) rowid.  Notice that you changed the *value* but not the *type* of the primary key in your sample above.  That's legal (provided the new value is unique), but changing it to e.g., 'abc' would not be.